# child_process.spawn returning stdout at once only on command completion but not in chunks during execution

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

code is as follows:

```
var exec = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = exec('executable.exe',['-nw','-nc','launch.txt']);
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log("STDOUT : ",data.toString());
});
child.stderr.on('data',function(data){
    console.log("STDERR : ",data.toString());
});
```

total output is some 20-25 lines and I'm expecting data in chunks but it only returns all the 20-25 at once and not in chunks

Please help me by telling what mistake I'm doing

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. I have noticed it seems to be triggered by how much data is coming through.

In the case where it doesn't come through in chunks, I had 3 lines of text, roughly in the region of 150 bytes. If I launched the same process with its verbose option, resulting in around 14k of output, then the `data` event fires in chunks as expected.

It's not a good solution, but it may be a viable work around.

Comment: Thanks @rastating.
Please can you explain more on how do I enable verbose option to get the data in chunks?

Comment: If the executable you are spawning supports it, you'd put it in the arguments list. For example: `var child = exec('executable.exe',['--verbose', '-nw','-nc','launch.txt']);`. In my case, the application supported doing so, which increased the amount of data, but that won't necessarily be true of all applications. It's not the best of solutions, but it's worth looking into if you're still having no luck.